# How do you add widgets to the lockscreen in KitKat?

Tags: lock-screens, app-widgets, 4.4-kitkat

Just got a Nexus 5 running KitKat (what else?), but I cannot figure out how to add widgets to the lockscreen! On JB, swiping right from the left edge while showing lockscreen would display a "+" widget option. This is no longer the case. Are lockscreen widgets gone?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check "Enable widgets" in Settings > Security. Then you can swipe right on the lockscreen as usual.

Comment: Why that? What's the connection between those two?

Comment: Does this also work with PIN or pattern enabled? As this was not the case in JB.