# Enable lock screen widgets, 4.4.2 Kitkat on Samsung Mega 6.3 LTE

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung

When I try to enable lock screen widgets in my Samsung Mega 6.3 LTE with Kitkat 4.4.2 from **Settings > Security** it has no "**Enable widgets**" which was the solution in [How do you add widgets to the lockscreen in KitKat?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56119/how-do-you-add-widgets-to-the-lockscreen-in-kitkat) and [How do I add a widget to my lock screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78041/how-do-i-add-a-widget-to-my-lock-screen).

How do I enable lock screen widgets in my Samsung Mega 6.3 SGH-M819N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  it DOES allow Lock Screen Widgets,  I found,  if the lock screen security is set to Swipe... instead of Password or other rigorous security options. Still experimenting with security options.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung's TouchWiz UI does not allow you to add lockscreen widgets in Kitkat as far as i know. My Galaxy Note 10.1 has the option named "lockscreen widgets" under settings, but its not anything like the stock Android Kitkat concept.

You have to install a custom ROM if you want that functionality. [image]